# Is $\Sigma_{1}^\infty(\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{\sqrt n})$ convergent?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I think I need to create some $\Sigma_{1}^\infty b_n$ to do the comparison. But I have no idea how to create $\Sigma_{1}^\infty b_n$

Comment: I guess $-n^{-1/2}$ works eventually.

Comment: Considering $\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{1}{n}\sim\ln N$ and $\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\sim 2\sqrt{N}$ (from Riemann sums), it must diverge to $-\infty$ (which is why Martund wrote the summands instead as $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}-\frac{1}{n}$ to get $+\infty$).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\sqrt n-1}{n}\geq\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\sqrt n}{2n}=\infty$$